# Laravel Docker returns 404 found

Tags: laravel, docker

I installed docker with nginx + mysql + laravel with php7.4

but it returns 404 not found, on laravel homepage (and on every routes)

Here's my docker-compose.yml

I used composer install, npm run etc. it installed all with success.

https://github.com/jjuanrivvera99/laravel-nginx-mysql-docker that is the url that im using.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    image: jjuanrivvera99/laravel:mysql-alpine
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  queue:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    image: jjuanrivvera99/laravel:mysql-alpine
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: "queue"
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/"
    networks:
      - app-network

  scheduler:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    image: jjuanrivvera99/laravel:mysql-alpine
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: "scheduler"
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/"
    networks:
      - app-network

  node:
    image: jjuanrivvera99/node:alpine
    restart: always
    build:
      context: docker/node
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: node
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mdpocr
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Bugbytes13**
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local

  redis-data:
    driver: local
```

And, heres my docker/nginx/app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    server_tokens off;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `php artisan cache:clear`  or `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: yeah I did but didnt work. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found                                                                                                                 
2021-05-19 07:02:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: maybe create a new route that uses a `function` instead of a controller to return a simple string, something like "/test" in web.php under routes folder. if it goes through, that means, it's something in the homepage route that's missing. 404 in laravel could mean a `Model` is missing, or a `route` is missing. so check that to make sure it's missing the route. and btw, it's always a good idea to include what you've tried in the question.